# Vue router - get 'from' path inside component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

What's the best way to get the "from" path inside a component, i.e. not using `router.beforeEach` in router/index.js?

I want to load a component for a route and show / hide DOM elements based on where the user came from.

`console.log(this.$route);` gives  me the current route, but I want the `history -1` route.

Comment: Have you tried watching the route with a watcher you can watch $route(to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [in-component `beforeRouteEnter` guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

```js
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  data: () => ({
    fromPath: ""
  }),
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.fromPath = from.path
    })
  }
}
```